How to query the containing partition of a file with KDE?
How to query the containing partition of a file with KDE?
I'm using KDE, and I'm toying with the idea of hacking the code for Dolphin File Manager (and potentially Konqueror if necessary) to get context-sensitive drag and drop behaviour (i.e. files are moved within the same partition, or copied if they're moved across partitions or the source is read only).
To do this, I think I'd need to find out the containing partition of the source and destination (easy enough on Windows using the drive letter, but on Linux, as mount points can be almost anywhere, it can't be reliably derived from the file path), and compare them. Does anyone know how I can find out the partition that contains a given file?
It must be possible - I know Nautilus provides this sort of behaviour, but I'm not familiar enough with GTK to track down the appropriate section in the source code to see how its done...

Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want.  As it is, we don't even know which language you're using! Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

@TobySpeight Nonsense, this is answerable as it is.

@dumbass, trying to answer without even knowing which programming language is a fool's errand.  It's not hard to fix the question to provide that basic information.


easy enough on Windows using the drive letter, but on Linux, as mount points can be almost anywhere, it can't be reliably derived from the file path

Starting with a bad assumption: Mount points can be almost anywhere on Windows, too – the ability to mount a volume on a folder was added in Windows 2000 (mountvol.exe, diskmgmt.msc, even the new Windows 11 'Settings' app), though it's implemented very  differently than Linux (using NTFS-level reparse points rather than VFS-level logic) but the result is the same: you cannot assume that C:\Data\Foo.txt is on the volume C:\ and not, for example, the C:\Data\ volume.
So at minimum, on both platforms you may need to get the list of all mounts from the OS – I think QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes() can do that in KDE/Qt – and try to find the longest matching prefix; e.g. by incrementally removing the last component of the absolute path until the remainder matches a mounted volume.
(The low-level Linux-specific mechanism involves reading /proc/self/mountinfo or /etc/mtab to get the list of mounts; on Windows you'd call GetLogicalDriveStrings() if you wanted to bypass Qt.)
Though it is still more complex on Linux as mounts can overlap in not necessarily "top-down" order (i.e. a mount higher in the hierarchy may cover a deeper one – for example, /mnt may cover /mnt/backup – usually by accident if the user sets them up in the wrong order), and the simple aforementioned approach of finding the longest matching prefix isn't really 100% accurate. (That being said, even many of the "standard" Linux tools get this wrong – so it may be acceptable for Dolphin to get it wrong, too.)
Based purely from the docs I'm reading, a better approach might be to create a QStorageInfo(string path) and then use its rootPath() property to have Qt figure it out, hopefully correctly.

To find the partition containing a file:
findmnt -no source -T file-path


For downvoters, please leave a comment so that answers can be improved.
